# Issue while trying to pass data from main.go to html

Tags: go

**About**

I am trying to pass data from main.go file to html and printing in stylesheet path...but due to some reasons it show blank page.

**main.go code**

```
var templates *template.Template
var pageDefault pageDefaults

type pageDefaults struct {
    cssUrl string
}

func loginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    pageDefault = pageDefaults{
        cssUrl: "hello"
    }
    templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.html"))
    templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "sample.html", pageDefault)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    switch strings.ToLower(r.URL.Path) {
    case "/login":
        loginHandler(w, r)
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

**html code**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{.cssUrl}}/test.css" />
```

Comment: Start by checking the error returned by [`templates.ExecuteTemplate`](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template#Template.ExecuteTemplate). Note that for a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you can remove the `http` stuff ([e.g.](https://go.dev/play/p/Sd7onFPpxuq)). Will remove goland tag as it's not relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in "[Struct Variable Names in Go Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20228783/6309)",  the Go templating engine uses reflection to get the values out of types it does not "know" about.

That means your `pageDefaults` struct should use an exported type name `PageDefaults`, and field `CssUrl`, not `cssUrl`.
As noted, you should check the error from [`ExecuteTemplate()`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#Template.ExecuteTemplate):

```golang
type PageDefaults struct {
    CssUrl string
}

func loginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    pageDefault = PageDefaults{
        CssUrl: "hello"
    }
    templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.html"))
    if err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "sample.html", pageDefault); err != nil {
        // Check error here.
    }
}
```

And your HTML code can refer to that exported field:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{.CssUrl}}/test.css" />
```